# Is it proper to perform a grammar edit of the entire post?

Tags: discussion

I edited every sentence of this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26916/what-is-the-catholicism-view-of-matthew-1820-in-this-technology-age) and the title, as well as moved the bible verse up a line as it made more sense in that sequence. (It still has to be approved).

I felt quite good doing it and think I could make a habit out of this.

Is this proper?

The positives are self evident.

However, if not being careful, editing grammar like this (every sentence) could result in a distortion of the original intention of the question.

Comment: I've made much bigger edits than that. See, for example, http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/16971/revisions, http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/24641/revisions, and http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/16121/revisions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Editing in general is to be encouraged and your edits in particular were an improvement so keep it up!

I would just add one consideration that you may not have been aware of. The first couple sentences of a question should generally not lead off with a quoted verse. This is because the system automatically generates an excerpt based an the first lines that gets used for summary pages, search results, notifications, etc. Leading off with a verse defeats the purpose and renders these excerpts useless. The excerpt should show something that summarizes the question or at least gives a clue as to the direction. A verse doesn't typically do this. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Alright, good to know; thanks.